# Проигрыватель FLV Android

Tags: flashvideo, android

Собственно, сабж.
Как в Андроид показать видео сего формата?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FLV не входит в [список](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html) поддерживаемых форматов, поэтому стандартными средствами этого сделать нельзя. Обычно конвертируют flv в mp4 и тп. Иногда поступают так:

1. устанавливают на устройство Flash Player;
2. добавляют в приложение webView;
3. загружают в webView HTML страницу, которая содержит плагин;
4. и проигрывают в плагине нужный flv.

Comment: Спасибо, и это прискорбно. Вот от концепции веб-браузера я и хотел отойти.

Answer (score 0):

Flash проигрывает форматы flv и f4v с большим числом способов кодирования (т.е. можно конвертнуть во что-то из того, что предлагает Adobe Media Encoder и что понимает андроид). Не могу сказать конкретно насчет андроида, но вообще флешевые приложения *не обязаны* работать через браузер и могут взаимодействовать с ОС (см. Flash AIR).

Answer (score 0):

http://board.riot.ru/showthread.php?t=16804&p=123241&viewfull=1#post123241